# How do i transfer contacts from old nokia symbian phone to windows phone?

Tags: sync

How do i transfer contacts from old nokia symbian phone to windows phone?

Also is there a way to sync sms from my old phone to windows phone?

Windows Phone is Nokia 710. My old Nokia Phone has bluetooth but it is refusing to connect to the new Windows Phone

Comment: Does your symbian have BlueTooth? Is your new phone a Nokia?

Answer (score 5):

There's a contact transfer app for Nokia Windows Phones.

Easy route: watch the youtube video showing the contact transfer process at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwZAWXyXYbU .

Have the micro SIM in your Nokia 710 and turn it on. You must use the micro SIM that comes with your Nokia Lumia, aka the one that was in the box.

In the application list you should find "Contact Transfer".  Follow the instructions and connect the two phones via Bluetooth.  Your contact will move from the old device to the new one.

Answer (score 5):

Built into every Nokia Windows Phone is a small utility, 'Contacts Transfer', providing a very quick way for Symbian smartphone owners to get their core contacts over to a replacement Windows Phone. Here's a walkthrough of this usefull utility in action.

1. Turn Bluetooth on in the source smartphone (on the N8, in Settings/Connectivity)
2. Start the utility and you'll be prompted to turn Bluetooth on. Do this and you'll be shown Bluetooth enabled devices nearby.
3. Tap the one you want and you'll be asked to confirm the connection on the other device in the usual way.

4.The Lumia will scan the contacts on the other smartphone (via PBAP) and report on the number of entries found. Tap on 'Continue' to proceed with the transfer, which should take a minute or so at most.

[this link might clear your doubts](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/13828_How_to_Get_your_contacts_direc.php)

Comment: Sorry but it is not entirely truth. I think this app Contacts Transfer is only build into *Nokia* Windows Phone.

Comment: Still working with a *Microsoft* Windows Phone (which, I think, is actually Nokia but with a different name).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WP8, follow these steps:

1. Install the [Transfer My Data](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=dc08943b-7b3d-4ee5-aa3c-30f1a826af02) app
2. Switch on Bluetooth on your old phone and ensure that it's visible to other devices.
3. Open the Transfer My Data app on your Windows phone, and now you can transfer contacts, text messages, pictures and music files.

Comment: This will NOT work for the op. He mentions that the new phone is a  Nokia 710. This does not run anything more that WP7.8. The Transfer My Data app only works with WP8 and WP8.1

Answer (score -1):

While this might not be the best method, I have found it best served what I needed when transferring my iphone contacts to my Android HTC:

http://fff.wf/hfSj

First, I don't have a Gmail account, and even if I had, I would not wish to mix my email addresses with my iphone address book by syncing Gmail with my iphone address book. As a result, I used the above method in order to manually export my iphone contacts to my computer and in turn import them to my new HTC phone.

Comment: Can you list a summary of the steps from the link? Links don't last forever and it would be nice to then know how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Link is not working

Answer (score -4):

Use a phone to phone tool.
May this tool will help you.
http://www.iphonetoandroidtransfer.com/

Comment: How would an iPhone-to-Android transfer tool help with moving from Symbian to Windows Phone?

Answer (score -5):

You can use google sync to solve the issue about [how to transfer contacts from Nokia to iPhone](http://iphone-contact-transfer.blogspot.com/2013/10/transfer-contacts-from-nokia-to-iphone.html).
1 Launch Mail Exchange on your Nokia phone and setup using the settings mentioned here .
2 Now use your iPhone and navigate to Settings app and go to Mail,Contacts,Calendar tab .
3 Add an account and select Microsoft Exchange . Enter all your google account details as shown here .
4 Now your Google Sync is ready . Sync to transfer your contacts.

Comment: The question doesn't mention iPhones at all, so I'm struggling to see the relevancy here?